# Search solutions to index Windows SMB file share

Tags: search, elasticsearch, smb, fileshare, sharepoint-search

I'm identifying search solutions that can crawl Windows SMB file shares and expose the search results through an API (with security trimming). So far, it seems like SharePoint and Elastic Search can handle this. But are there other possible solutions?

Answer (score 3):

this tool (a filesystem indexer that useses Elasticsearch as a backend) is made specifically for this use case:
https://github.com/shirosaidev/diskover

You could - for example - create a Linux machine, mount the SMB share there as read-only and let Diskover index that path.